# Principal Radical Ideal

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $R=k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ be a standard graded polynomial algebra over a field $k$ ($k$ can be algebraically closed if you want).  Is there a homogeneous prime ideal $P\subset R$ for which the integral domain $R/P$ has no non-trivial principal radical ideal?  I am asking because I recently stumbled across [Proposition 15.111.10](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BWR) on the Stacks Project, which makes me believe that such creatures might exist, but I'm having trouble coming up with $P$'s that aren't Cohen-Macaulay or normal...if someone knows an example or a reference that would be great :-)

Comment: Have you tried $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ and $P=(x^3+y^3+z^3)$?

Comment: @Mohan, thanks for the example...this seems to be in the right spirit, although I think (x) + P is a principal ideal of R/P...

Comment: My answer was just one where there are no principal prime ideal, not merely radical. If $k$ is infinite, Bertini would say that there are lots of radical principal ideals.